# "People talk of situations" or "People talk over situations" in Bob Dylan's Love Minus Zero?

Tags: lyrics

I am listening to Bob Dylan's *Love Minus Zero*.
There is a sentence I am not sure.
That is,

"People talk **of** situations"

or

"People talk **over** situations".

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9w1mCevu3sU), it sounds like "over". But some [sources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZzyRcySgK8) said that it is "of". Could anyone check it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is ... **both**. Dylan prefers "over"; everyone else sings "of".

In the [recording posted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9w1mCevu3sU&t=1m19s), this [1965 recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVw6PyYhto4&t=1m6s), this other [1965 recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2Ia7Ceq3RY&t=1m45s), this [1971 recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufbHfGU7WxA&t=1m1s), this [1975 recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZFofeneE5E&t=50s), and this [1999 recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1i058hCJGEU&t=1m29s) Dylan clearly sings "over".

But in the [original recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZzyRcySgK8&t=38s) on *Bringing It All Back Home*, he sings "of".

And "of" is the popular way to go for covers. For example, all of the following covers include "of".
[Eliza Gilkyson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXnpykgIUc4&t=37s), [Rod Stewart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETtZZHSgdbg&t=1m22s), [Eric Clapton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XTrBtSCT64&t=1m13s), and [Jackson Browne](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tfs4Gi0T430&t=43s).